# pass a file between libraries without saving to disk

Tags: python, image, opencv, kivy

I'm currently trying to take a video and extract its frames in openCV, and then use those frames in Kivy.

currently, I save the frames to disk in openCV, and then open the image from file in kivy.

however, since I'm doing this numerous times per second, kivy occasionally goes for the file before openCV is finished with it, causing it to crash.

is there any way to pass the image between these two libraries that doesn't have this downside? Kivy for one seems pretty intent on opening images from file, and I'm not sure how else to store them.

edit: added code

```
#openCV2 part#
video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
success, image = video.read()
cv2.imwrite("savename.jpg", image)

#Kivy part#
canvas.add(Rectangle(source="savename.jpg", pos=self.pos, size=self.size))
```

Comment: show your code, then it is easier to «repair» it.

Comment: Are we talking inter process communication here? If so fifo's (named pipes) might be a solution.

Comment: @Daniel I'm trying, but it keeps smooshing it into one long line. is there anywhere with a good explanation of how to format code here?

Comment: @DavidRobertsson it's all more or less in the same process, it's just that each library has its own image class and they're not compatible as far as I know

Comment: @GrayWynters: There is a `{}`-Button for code.

Comment: @Daniel ah, I was trying to add it in the comments. my bad.

Comment: Maybe https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.image.html#in-memory-image-loading ? | In opencv, use [imencode](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imencode).

Comment: @DanMašek I've given this a go, and it looks like it might work, but I've had a little trouble.

the in-memory image loading on the kivy end seems fine, but it doesn't seem to like the data I get from imencode in openCV. I keep getting the error `Exception: Unable to load imag type array` and then just lists an array that I assume is the output from openccv (lots of 2/3 digit numbers and a "dtype=unit8"